# Delete duplicate value from array of array

Tags: javascript, list, validation, duplicates

I have an object array and I want to avoid to duplicate value with a specific key value.

This is an objectArray.

```
   var dept = 
 [
    {
  "department": [
    { "userName": "cds",
      "userId": "33",
      "userFirstname": "Chef",
      "userLastname": "Jone"
    },
    {
      "userName": "asset1",
      "userId": "27",
      "userFirstname": "Asset",
      "userLastname": "Ann "
    }
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "doc": null
},
{
  "department": [
    { 
      "userName": "audit1",
      "userId": "32",
      "userFirstname": "Audit",
      "userLastname": "Kim"
    },
    { "userName": "cds",
      "userId": "33",
      "userFirstname": "Chef",
      "userLastname": "Jone"
    }
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "doc": null
    }
 ];
```

I tried to return the unduplicated object by javascript.
But the result seems different. 
I can return the value from one object array. However, I feel difficulties to extract the values from array of array. 
How to assign a filter array of an array? 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
   function getUnique(dept, comp) { 

  const unique = dept
   .map(e => e[comp])

 // store the keys of the unique objects
.map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

// eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
.filter(e => dept[e]).map(e => dept[e]);

  return unique;
  }

return getUnique(dept,'userName');
```

I would get the result

```
 [
{
  "department": [
    { "userName": "cds",
      "userId": "33",
      "userFirstname": "Chef",
      "userLastname": "Jone"
    },
    {
      "userName": "asset1",
      "userId": "27",
      "userFirstname": "Asset",
      "userLastname": "Ann "
    }
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "doc": null
},
{
  "department": [
    { 
      "userName": "audit1",
      "userId": "32",
      "userFirstname": "Audit",
      "userLastname": "Kim"
    } 
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "doc": null
    }
  ];
```

However, I got the result

```
   [
    {
"department": [
 { "userName": "cds",
    "userId": "33",
    "userFirstname": "Chef",
    "userLastname": "Jone"
 },
 {
      "userName": "asset1",
      "userId": "27",
      "userFirstname": "Asset",
      "userLastname": "Ann "
  }
],
"comment": "",
"doc": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of map and filter

```js
var dept =[{"department": [{ "userName": "cds","userId": "33","userFirstname": "Chef","userLastname": "Jone"},{"userName": "asset1","userId": "27","userFirstname": "Asset","userLastname": "Ann "}],"comment": "","doc": null},{ "department": [{ "userName": "audit1","userId": "32","userFirstname": "Audit","userLastname": "Kim"},{ "userName": "cds","userId": "33","userFirstname": "Chef","userLastname": "Jone"}],"comment": "","doc": null}];
 
let tracker = {}
let op = dept.map(val => {
  let department = val.department
  let filtered = department.filter(({userId}) => {
    if(tracker[userId] !== undefined ){
      return false
    } else {
      tracker[userId] = userId
      return true
    }
  })
  return {...val,department: filtered}
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works perfectly. I appreciate your help.